# Transparency for WPF UI elements

Tags: wpf, transparency

Is it possible in WPF to make a certain element - say, a `Canvas` containing a button - semi-transparent? All I could find so far is how to make a whole window transparent or making the background of WPF shapes transparent; but that's not what I need.

Please provide the answers either in XAML or C# - I don't speak Visual Basic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something along the lines of this perhaps? **`Opacity`** is probably what you are looking for

```
<Button Width="200" Height="30" Opacity="0.5">
    Click Me!
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I always was looking for "transparency" but failed to look for "opacity".

Comment: No problem :) Please mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the gray tick to green) so others looking for same thing would know that this question has an answer for them as well.

Comment: Just did it. The problem was that you answered my question too quickly and StackOverflow wouldn't let me mark your answer as accepted with the first 15 minutes or so.

Comment: lol sorry! I didn't know it had that limit :) but thank you for coming back to do it. much appreciated :)